# SQLite Delete function working but not deleting entry

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

The record is selected from a ListView which can then be clicked on, promting the user with a dialog to see if they would like to confirm or cancel.
The record should then be deleted and the ListView should update. However, I haven't been able to achieve this so far despite the provided tutorial matching up with my code. The application does not crash but after the dialog, it refreshes the page but does not delete the record?

DeleteRecord Actvity

```
public class DeleteRecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    OpenDatabase sqh;
    SQLiteDatabase sqdb;

    ListView deleteRecordListView;
    Button backButtonDelete;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_delete_record);

        InitDatabase();

        setupControls();

    } //  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

    public void InitDatabase()
    {
        sqh = new OpenDatabase(this);
        sqdb = sqh.getWritableDatabase();

    } //  public void InitDatabase()

    protected void setupControls()
    {
        backButtonDelete = findViewById(R.id.backButtonDelete);
        backButtonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                finish();
            }
        });

        setupListView();

    } //  protected void setupControls()

    protected void setupListView()
    {
        deleteRecordListView = findViewById(R.id.deleteRecordListview);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.addAll( sqh.allFilmsReturnArrayList( sqdb ));

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        deleteRecordListView.setAdapter( adapter );

        deleteRecordListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
            {
                String item = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

               // String[] subString = item.split(",");

               // sqh.deleteRecordFromFilmography( sqdb, subString[0] );

                deleteRecordDialog( item );

                Log.i("RECORD", "Record = " + item);

                refreshListView();

            }
        });


    } // protected void setupListView()

    protected void refreshListView()
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.addAll( sqh.allFilmsReturnArrayList( sqdb ));

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);

        deleteRecordListView.setAdapter( adapter );

    } // protected void refreshListView()

    protected void deleteRecordDialog(String selectedRecord)
    {
        String[] subString = selectedRecord.split(",");

        Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialog_layout);

        TextView recordTextView = dialog.findViewById(R.id.recordTextView);
        recordTextView.setText( selectedRecord );

        Button yesButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.yesButton);
        yesButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                sqh.deleteRecordFromFilmography( sqdb, subString[0] );
                dialog.dismiss();
                refreshListView();;
            }
        });

        Button noButton = dialog.findViewById(R.id.noButton);
        noButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });

        dialog.show();

    } //   protected void deleteRecordDialog(String selectedRecord)



} // public class DeleteRecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity
```

The call method in the OpenDatabase class:

```
public void deleteRecordFromFilmography(SQLiteDatabase sqdb, String id)
    {
        String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM filmography WHERE id = '" + id + ";'";

        sqdb.execSQL( deleteQuery );

    } // public void deleteRecordfromFilmography(SQLiteDatabase sqdb, String id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know which tutorial you are following, but my advice is to stop and find something else.

The problem with your code is just a typo:

```
String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM filmography WHERE id = '" + id + "';";
```

instead of:

```
String deleteQuery = "DELETE FROM filmography WHERE id = '" + id + ";'";
```

**But** by fixing just that you will only learn to use unsafe code and prone to typos like that.

Your code is unsafe because you are concatenating parameters to sql code.
This is always a bad idea and poses the risk of [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

Use `?` placeholders for the parameters.

The recommended method to delete a row is **not** [`execSQL()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#execSQL(java.lang.String)) but [`delete()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase#delete(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D)):

```
public void deleteRecordFromFilmography(SQLiteDatabase sqdb, String id) {
    sqdb.delete("filmography", "id = ?", new String[] {id});
}
```

The 1st argument is the name of the table, the 2nd is the `WHERE` clause without the `WHERE` keyword and the 3d is an array of strings which contains the values for the parameters (`?` placeholders) which is only 1 in your case.

Comment: Same issue once the typo has been corrected and changing to your code so I'm missing something?

Yeah sadly these tutorials are for my masters software engineering course.. I assumed it was just me overlooking things but nope, that's how he does them so I think I'll take your advice and look elsewhere for materials aha.

Comment: @PaleHorse if the row is not deleted then maybe the `id` that you pass does not exist in the table. `delete()` returns the number of rows deleted. So do something like: `int x = sqdb.delete("filmography", "id = ?", new String[] {id});` and print the value of x. If it is 0 then there is no row with that id.

Comment: @PaleHorse also print the `id` to make sure that it has a valid nvalue.

Comment: Yeah I wont lie all this is pretty above me right now like I say got thrown into the deep end don't know why they advertised the course as for beginners.  Im not sure how to do that with Java...

Comment: @PaleHorse it's a good idea to start with the official documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase There you can find everything you need for accessing SQLite databases. There are methods for selecting, inserting, updating and deleting rows.

Comment: Thanks for all your help! At that point now as long as I can score a C I'm happy.